# iMac boots up at 9:30AM every day

Tags: macos, mac, imac

I don’t know why this is happening? In order to solve this problem, I have to turn of the power strip, which sometimes I can’t.

It keeps waking me up whenever it does.

Comment: It thinks you should be up by then :)

Comment: No, seriously has the auto start been set ? Or wake on network activity - in the system preferences...

Comment: Re ^ System Prefs > Energy Saver > Schedule

Comment: @Tetsujin, it was on the schedule, which I assumed it was because what other thing would that be. I did not set this so that is the strange thing. Thanks! Create an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: It was @SolarMike who posted the idea first - I just pointed out where the setting was. If he wants to pick it up & post as an answer, that would seem only fair.

Comment: Cheers guys - glad you are sorted anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has the auto start been set ? Or wake on network activity - in the system preferences...

As the comment from Tetsujin , system preferences - energy saver - schedule ..